# DataMapper::UpdateConflictError

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

Guys I hav below code snippet and I need remove an element from `animals` array, but I get `UpdateConflictError`

```
zoo.animals # => Wolf,Tiger,Lion
zoo.animals.delete("Wolf") # => Tiger, Lion
zoo.update(:animals => zoo.animals)
# => DataMapper::UpdateConflictError: Zoo#update cannot be called on a dirty resource
zoo.update #=> also give me the same error
```

I have to query the `zoo.animals` and then remove `Wolf` but seems not successful. What you recommend? thanks.

P.S: [here datamapper](http://datamapper.org/docs/create_and_destroy.html) has explained about dirty resources but I have no other alternative.

Comment: Just first select the right object, and call the correct method, i.e., `zoo.animals.get("Wolf").destroy` (`get` uses the primary key, so another option would be the `.first(:property => "Wolf")`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has resolved the error:

```
zoo.animals # => Wolf,Tiger,Lion
zoo.animals.delete("Wolf") # => Tiger, Lion
zoo.save
```